# Back with another one-line wonder!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> When a roman emperor tilted his head, he became nothing.

Why?

Comment: Oh man - can someone point out which of the answers below came first? :/

Comment: You can sort by oldest. It was Deusovi.

Comment: @Deusovi by a whole 58 seconds! We must have both been writing up simultaneously (I was using a phone so did not get the push notification to say an answer had just been posted...). Formatting cost me...

Comment: @PilsNot3 ok, thanks for the advice. I’ll ensure that will happen in future - for now, I’ll reduct the extra commentary. Thanks for letting me know! :)

Comment: Thanks @Stiv! (P.S. Would you like for me to give you a bounty offer to make up for a checkmark, given that you had the answer but just couldn’t post it in time?)

Comment: No need - all part of the Puzzling experience :) Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because

> the emperor is "Nero", and when the letter N is tilted sideways it turns into a Z, making it "Zero".

Comment: It seems I have forgotten how clever the Puzzling community is, over the course of my absence. Well done ;)

Comment: Congratulations, @Deusovi! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 19):

The Roman Emperor is:

> **NERO**

When he 'tilted his head', he:

> Rotated his initial letter by 90 degrees. Thus 'N' became 'Z'.

Thus making him become:

> **ZERO** (i.e. 'nothing')!

Comment: Yes, that is correct - and very quick too! Great job! :P